# batch length is always one in kafka masstransit Batchconsumer

Tags: masstransit

i tried these configuration to consume batch messages but i always receive one message per batch

```
config.AddRider(config =>
            {

                config.AddConsumer<PlatformDataBatchConsumerKafkaService>();
                config.UsingKafka((ct, cf) =>
                {
                    cf.Host(kafkaConfig.HostUrl);
                    
                    cf.TopicEndpoint<BrokerPlatformTransaction>(kafkaConfig.TopicName, kafkaConfig.ConsumerGroupName, e =>
                            {
                                e.PrefetchCount = 100;
                                
                                e.ConfigureConsumer<PlatformDataBatchConsumerKafkaService>(ct, configurator =>
                                {
                                    configurator.Options<BatchOptions>(op =>
                                    {
                                        op.SetMessageLimit(2);
                                       
                                    });
                                });
                                

                            });


                });



            });
```

i got the batch with one message only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest [reviewing the documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/transports/kafka#scalability) on scalability and determine the appropriate settings.

My guess is that all your messages have the same key and are in the same partition, for which the default is to deliver one message a time. If that's the case, you can increase the `ConcurrentDeliveryLimit` to satisfy the batch message limit.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your reply , setting the ConcurrentDeliveryLimit  woked fine